# Remove folder in bitbucket

Tags: java, git, bitbucket

I originally had my eclipse project in Bitbucket in Bitbucket. I changed the package name of the project and attempted to push but it would not let me so I used git push -f and it pushed my new package name but it kept the old one also. I am not sure what happened since I am new to git. How could I delete the old one or how could I complete remove everything in my bitbucket repo and just have what I have with the new package name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If eclipse did rename your package, that means you should not have anymore your old folder representing the old package.

Switch to the command line, and confirm that with `git status`: it should show you that old package as deleted.

If so:

```
cd /path/to/your/project/src
git add -A .
git commit -m "record deletion of old package"
git push
```

Then BitBucket will reflect the deletion of the old package.